# How do I get all paths to tree leafs using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, tree

How do I get all paths to tree leafs using Javascript?

I tried to use the `arboreal` package, but I could simply parse it to an array or something like this if it helps.

My data looks like this:

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   /   / \
  4   6   5
 /
7
```

I want to get an output like this:

> [1,2,4,7], [1,3,6], [1,3,5]

Comment: What does your input really look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: real input is to complicated, but broken down looks like that. later on I want to get some values of the nodes an summarize them and so on. What exactly you want to know about the input?

Comment: Can't tell you how to get an output without knowing the input.

Comment: all nodes look like this: node{time:15}, then I want to calculate the times of each branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could visit all nodes and if the node has no more children, you could store the actual path in the result set.

```js
function getPath(object) {
    function iter(o, p)  {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        if (keys.length) {
            return keys.forEach(function (k) {
                iter(o[k], p.concat(k));        
            });
        }
        result.push(p);
    }
    
    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var object = { 1: { 2: { 4: { 7: {} } }, 3: { 6: {}, 5: {} } } };

console.log(getPath(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: dear, here is a similar question that might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011033/print-all-paths-to-leafs-of-a-tree-like-list-array-and-concatenate-corresponding