# Print all paths to leafs of a tree-like list array and concatenate corresponding values in the path

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array consisting of keys and values where keys are a tree like numbered list.
**This is the input array:**

```
inputArr =     [
                ["1", "I can "], 
                ["1.1", "speak "],
                ["1.1.1", "English."], 
                ["1.1.2", "Chinese "], 
                ["1.1.2.1", "well."], 
                ["1.2", "eat noodles."],
                ["1.3", "play football."],
                ["2", "I "],
                ["2.1", "drink."],
                ["2.2", "sleep."],
                ["3", "I am the man."],
                ["4", "Hire me."]
               ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
outputArr =    [
                ["1.1.1", "I can speak English."],
                ["1.1.2.1", "I can speak Chinese well."],
                ["1.2", "I can eat noodles."],
                ["1.3", "I can play football."],
                ["2.1", "I drink."],
                ["2.2", "I sleep."],
                ["3", "I am the man."],
                ["4", "Hire me."]
               ]
```

**Let me explain the first output:**
The first leaf in the inputArray is `"1.1.1"`. It's path is: `"1"->"1.1"->"1.1.1"`. When the
values in the path are concatenated: `"I can " + "speak " + "English."`.

I have studied all the relevant stackoverflow questions. I have got no clues to my problem.

**I am thinking of an algorithm like this:**

```
iterating from bottom of the array:
if the key length is 1, it is a root parent item.
if the key above has length >1, it is a leaf item. Now, get path by splitting the key, and concatenate the corresponding values.
```

I have tried editing Bit's code. But it only works partially. The code I have used is:

```
function getSentences(arr) {

  let outputArr = [],
    s = [],
    curr, next;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    curr = arr[i];
    next = arr[i + 1];

    if (curr[0].length == 1) {
      s.push(curr[1]);
      if (curr[0].length == next[0].length) outputArr.push([curr[0], s.join('')]);
    } else if (curr[0].length < next[0].length) {
      s.push(curr[1]);
    } else if (curr[0].length >= next[0].length) {
      outputArr.push([curr[0], s.join('') + curr[1]]);
      if (curr[0].length > next[0].length) {
        s.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; s.length == next[0].length; i++) {
    s.pop()
  }
  s.push(next[1])
  outputArr.push([next[0], s.join('')])

  return outputArr

}


var inputArr = [
  ["1", "I can "],
  ["1.1", "speak "],
  ["1.1.1", "English."],
  ["1.1.2", "Chinese "],
  ["1.1.2.1", "well."],
  ["1.2", "eat noodles."],
  ["1.3", "play football."],
  ["2", "I "],
  ["2.1", "drink."],
  ["2.2", "sleep."],
  ["3", "I am the man."],
  ["4", "Hire me."]
];

var outputArr = getSentences(inputArr);
console.log(outputArr);
```

Can you suggest any correction or update, any alternative piece of code, any algorithm or hint about the problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nitheesh
updated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a tree first and the get the connected pathes and strings.

```js
const
    getPathes = ({ value = '', sub }) => sub
        ? Object
            .entries(sub)
            .flatMap(([k, v]) => getPathes(v).map(([p, s]) => [k + (p && '.') + p, value + (value && '') + s]))
        : [['', value]],
    input = [["1", "I can "], ["1.1", "speak "], ["1.1.1", "English."], ["1.1.2", "Chinese "], ["1.1.2.1", "well."], ["1.2", "eat noodles."], ["1.3", "play football."], ["2", "I "], ["2.1", "drink."], ["2.2", "sleep."], ["3", "I am the man."], ["4", "Hire me."]],
    tree = input.reduce((t, [path, value]) => {
        path.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o.sub ??= {})[k] ??= {}, t).value = value;
        return t;
    }, {}),
    result = getPathes(tree);

console.log(result);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: WOW! could you add some comments or explanations? I am working on adobe acrobat pro DC javascript debugger. This code doesn't run there. "SyntaxError: missing : after property id" error is shown.

Comment: acrobat pro DC javascript debugger uses javascript 1.7. What could be done to make your code compatible?

Comment: can you add the position of the error?

Comment: I have detailed related questions in another post. This might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142076/converting-a-javascript-code-to-an-older-javascript-version-1-7-the-code-prints

Comment: if I want to treat duplicate entries as extension of one, how can I handle that? for example, `[["1","x"],["1.2", "a"],["1.2", "b"],["1.2", "c"],["1.2.1","d"],["1.2.2","y"]]` should give me output `[["1.2.1", "xabcd"],["1.2.2","xabcy"]]`. Here, `["1.2", "a"],["1.2", "b"],["1.2", "c"]` means  `["1.2", "abc"]`.

Comment: the comments is to small please ask a new question.

Comment: sure! adding as a new question. please wait.

Comment: thanks for the quick help. I have posted a question with two new relevant issues (duplicate keys and tailing 'x') here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324202/print-all-paths-to-leafs-of-a-tree-like-list-array-and-concatenate-corresponding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is always properly sorted, like in the example, we can do this in linear time using a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). The basic algorithm would be like this:

- init the stack with a dummy item
- take each data item
- compare data item with the top of the stack (TOS)
- if the item > TOS (like 1.1 > 1), push it to the stack and continue
- otherwise, output everything on the stack concatenated
- while item <= TOS, keep popping items off the stack
- in the end, output everything that's left on the stack

Comment: how do I compare? for example, 1.1 with 1.1.2?

Comment: You actually can just compare their "levels", that is, the number of dots (`x.split('.').length`)

Answer (score 1):

This can be definitely improved, but it works.

```
function getSentences(arr) {

  let outputArr = [], s = [], curr, next;

  for (let i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    curr = arr[i];
    next = arr[i+1];

    if (curr[0].length == 1) {
      s.push(curr[1]);
      if (curr[0].length == next[0].length) outputArr.push([curr[0], s.join('')]);
    }

    else if (curr[0].length < next[0].length) {
      s.push(curr[1]);
    }

    else if (curr[0].length >= next[0].length) {
      outputArr.push([curr[0], s.join('') + curr[1]]);
      if (curr[0].length > next[0].length) {
        s.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  for (i=0; s.length == next[0].length; i++) {
    s.pop()
  }
  s.push(next[1])
  outputArr.push([next[0], s.join('')])

  console.log(outputArr);
  return outputArr

}
```

This function assumes something like "1.12.2" shouldn't exist and that the array is sorted like in the example.
If you want it to work with the hypothetical "1.12.2", replace `.length` in the comparisons with `path.replace(/[^.]/g, "").length`

Comment: would it make any difference if I use `.split(".").length` instead if `.replace(/[^.]/g, "").length` ?

Comment: @ImranAlRashid | The only difference is the minimum returned value, that is 0 instead of 1 in the case of `.replace(/[^.]/g, "").length`. So maybe use `.split(".").length`, which is easier to read.

Comment: when I include another element   ["1.1.2.1", " well."] in the input array, the code fails.