# Converting a JavaScript code to an older JavaScript version 1.7 (the code prints all paths to leafs of a tree-like list array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

### I want to write the following code using an older JavaScript version 1.7.

The following code prints all paths to leafs of a tree-like list array and concatenate corresponding values in the path. This code builds a tree first and the get the connected paths and strings.

Thanks to Nina Scholz for the code. For more explanation of the problem, the link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134761/14792779).

```js
const
  getPathes = ({
    value = '',
    sub
  }) => sub ?
  Object
  .entries(sub)
  .flatMap(([k, v]) => getPathes(v).map(([p, s]) => [k + (p && '.') + p, value + (value && '') + s])) :
  [
    ['', value]
  ],
  input = [
    ["1", "I can "],
    ["1.1", "speak "],
    ["1.1.1", "English."],
    ["1.1.2", "Chinese "],
    ["1.1.2.1", "well."],
    ["1.2", "eat noodles."],
    ["1.3", "play football."],
    ["2", "I "],
    ["2.1", "drink."],
    ["2.2", "sleep."],
    ["3", "I am the man."],
    ["4", "Hire me."]
  ],
    tree = input.reduce((t, [path, value]) => {
        path.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o.sub ??= {})[k] ??= {}, t).value = value;
        return t;
    }, {}),
  result = getPathes(tree);

console.log(result);
console.log(tree);
/*
Expected output:
               [
                ["1.1.1", "I can speak English."],
                ["1.1.2.1", "I can speak Chinese well."],
                ["1.2", "I can eat noodles."],
                ["1.3", "I can play football."],
                ["2.1", "I drink."],
                ["2.2", "I sleep."],
                ["3", "I am the man."],
                ["4", "Hire me."]
               ]
*/
```

This works fine. No problem. **But I want to achieve the same output using an older JavaScript version 1.7.**

I have come to know that JavaScript version 1.7 does not support the use of the Object.entries() method and the flatMap() method, as well as destructuring assignment, default values, and the nullish coalescing operator (??=).

### What I have tried so far

The following code is what I have achieved so far. The output is close, but not as expected. **The problem is - all the elements in the output contains a 'NaN'.**

```js
function getPathes(obj) {
  if (!obj.sub) {
    return [
      ['', obj.value]
    ];
  }
  var entries = [];
  for (var key in obj.sub) {
    if (obj.sub.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      entries.push([key, obj.sub[key]]);
    }
  }
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var key = entries[i][0];
    var value = entries[i][1];
    var pathes = getPathes(value);
    for (var j = 0; j < pathes.length; j++) {
      var p = pathes[j][0];
      var s = pathes[j][1];
      output.push([key + (p && '.') + p, obj.value + (obj.value && '') + s]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var input = [
  ["1", "I can "],
  ["1.1", "speak "],
  ["1.1.1", "English."],
  ["1.1.2", "Chinese "],
  ["1.1.2.1", "well."],
  ["1.2", "eat noodles."],
  ["1.3", "play football."],
  ["2", "I "],
  ["2.1", "drink."],
  ["2.2", "sleep."],
  ["3", "I am the man."],
  ["4", "Hire me."]
];
var tree = {};
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var path = input[i][0];
  var value = input[i][1];
  var parts = path.split('.');
  var current = tree;
  for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
    var k = parts[j];
    if (!current.sub) {
      current.sub = {};
    }
    if (!current.sub[k]) {
      current.sub[k] = {};
    }
    current = current.sub[k];
  }
  current.value = value;
}
var result = getPathes(tree);
console.log(result);

/*
Expected output:
               [
                ["1.1.1", "I can speak English."],
                ["1.1.2.1", "I can speak Chinese well."],
                ["1.2", "I can eat noodles."],
                ["1.3", "I can play football."],
                ["2.1", "I drink."],
                ["2.2", "I sleep."],
                ["3", "I am the man."],
                ["4", "Hire me."]
               ]
*/
```

### What I want is...

I want to find and correct the error.

I want to improve it to a better and simpler code.

I want to know if I could achieve the expected output in any other way.

### Could you...

Could you suggest any correction or update, any alternative piece of code, any algorithm or hint about the problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you limited to a version of [javascript that came out in 2006](https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/JavaScript/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1-7.html#:~:text=JavaScript%201.7%20is%20a%20language,let%20expressions%2C%20and%20destructuring%20assignment.)?

Comment: I want to use in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC which runs on JavaScript 1.7.

Comment: Maybe you can play with WSH, file.js in commandline or cscript file.js or wscript file.js has also similar old JS (?) or tag example (using that in HTA, which has also quite old JS) <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10">

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to write an old-version code.
You should use compiler tools(such as Bable) to convert your code in a  compatible version. Config the browser target as 'ie 6' which runs very old version of javascript, then the compiler tools will add the pollyfills as you need.

For example, open [Babel online playground](https://babeljs.io/repl), set the target for 'ie 6', input your code in the left, then get the result in the right.[image: Babel online playground]

If you are using Angular, you can add a `.browserslistrc` file in root directory. Learn more from [Configuring browser compatibility](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility)