# Array filter and conditionally change values in the subarrays after last duplicate index

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const inputArr = [
  ["1.3","6"],
  ["1.4", "7"],
  ["1.4", "7"],
  ["1.4x", "s"],
  ["1.4x", "g"],
  ["1.4x", "9"], //here is an element with tailing 'x', 
                 //search for "1.4" in the next subarrays 
  ["2","8"],     
  ["2.1x","9"],
  ["2.2.2","12"],
  ["1.4", "13"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
  ["1.4", "14"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
  ["2.1","92"],
  ["3","15"],
  ["4","16"]
]
```

**I want to create a new array using following conditions:**

1. Filter for unique strings with tailing 'x' (`for example,"1.4x"`)in the the first elements of the subarrays.
2. Then for each of the filtered items, look in the subsequent subarrays (not in the preceding subarrays) for strings that matches with the item without tailing 'x'. (`For example, for "1.4x" look for "1.4" in the subsequent subarrays.`)
3. If match found, add a tailing 'x' to them.

So, the expected new array created from the array above would be:

```
newArr = [
      ["1.3","6"],
      ["1.4", "7"],
      ["1.4", "7"],
      ["1.4x", "s"],
      ["1.4x", "g"],
      ["1.4x", "9"],
      ["2","8"],
      ["2.1x","9"],
      ["2.2.2","12"],
      ["1.4x", "13"], //changed "1.4" to "1.4x"
      ["1.4x", "14"], //changed "1.4" to "1.4x"
      ["2.1x","92"],  //changed "2.1" to "2.1x"
      ["3","15"],
      ["4","16"]
    ]
```

---

I have filtered the unique items with tailing 'x' this way:

```
const filteredItems = inputArr.filter(([key, value]) => key.endsWith("x"));
const uniqueFilteredItems =[...new Set(filteredItems.map(([k]) => k))]
console.log(
  uniqueFilteredItems
);
```

I am at a loss how to do the rest. Can you help?

Comment: Is it also only the first entries that need to be manipulated - or could `1.4` also come in the second position, and would need to be modified to `1.4x` in there as well then?

Comment: In the original array, `'1.4x'` is an item with tailing 'x'. It has duplicates. Last duplicate is at index 5. You have to manipulate after index 5. Look for `'1.4'` after index 5. And change all found after index 5 to `'1.4x'`

Comment: You just repeated what was already known, and did not actually answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. By 'second position' you mean 'second element in the subarrays', right? Then the answer is no. Only the first element needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use `map` methods and on each array check if the first value ends with `x`, if `yes` store it in an array without `x` at the end let's call the array `valuesWithX`, if `no` then check in the `valuesWithX` array if this value exists then concatenate with `x`.

```js
const inputArr = [
  ["1.3","6"],
  ["1.4", "7"],
  ["1.4", "7"],
  ["1.4x", "s"],
  ["1.4x", "g"],
  ["1.4x", "9"], //here is an element with tailing 'x', 
                 //search for "1.4" in the next subarrays 
  ["2","8"],     
  ["2.1x","9"],
  ["2.2.2","12"],
  ["1.4", "13"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
  ["1.4", "14"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
  ["2.1","92"],
  ["3","15"],
  ["4","16"]
]

const valuesWithX = []

const result = inputArr.map((value) => {
  const [first] = value;
  if (first.endsWith('x') ){
    valuesWithX.push(first.slice(0, -1));
  } else {
    if (valuesWithX.includes(first)) {
      value[0] = first + 'x';
    }
  }
  return [...value];
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is way too complicated, IMHO.

You do not actually want to *filter* your array in the first place - filtering means making the decision, which elements should stay in the result, and which should be removed. Not what you want here to begin with - you want to keep *all* items, you only want to manipulate the content of some of them.

Forget your fancy array functions - and just loop over it. (Your requirement to only manipulate *following* items - already built-in with that approach!)

```
let helper = {};
inputArr.forEach(function(e) {
  if(e[0].endsWith("x")) {
    helper[e[0].substr(0, e[0].length-1)] = true;
  } else if(helper[e[0]]){
    e[0] = e[0] + "x";
  }
})

console.log(inputArr)
```

We use a helper object to simply "remember" the elements ending with `x` we found already. (Cutting the `x` off at that point.)

And if for the next item, a corresponding property on that object already exists - then the current item gets its `x` added to it.

Answer (score 1):

To only affect non-x entries *after* the corresponding x entry was encountered, you can better not build the set *after* filtering, but during that iteration:

```js
const inputArr = [["1.3","6"],["1.4", "7"],["1.4", "7"],["1.4x", "s"],["1.4x", "g"],["1.4x", "9"],["2","8"],["2.1x","9"],["2.2.2","12"],["1.4", "13"],["1.4", "14"],["2.1","92"],["3","15"],["4","16"]];

const result = inputArr.map(function (pair) {
    const [key, value] = pair;
    if (this.has(key + "x")) return [key + "x", value];
    if (key.endsWith("x")) this.add(key);
    return pair;
}, new Set); // thisArg in map-callback is a Set

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is a `["2.1x","9"]` the array. So `["2.1","92"]` needs to be changed to `["2.1x","92"]`

Comment: Oh, yes, I did it in the opposite way. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator `[a,b]` contains the output array `a`, and `b` which is a set of elements that have been observed to end with `x`.

Every time we add each pair to the output array, we check the first element of the pair to see if it's in the `b` list, and adjust it if necessary.

```js
const inputArr = [["1.3","6"],["1.4","7"],["1.4","7"],["1.4x","s"],["1.4x","g"],["1.4x","9"],["2","8"],["2.1x","9"],["2.2.2","12"],["1.4","13"],["1.4","14"],["2.1","92"],["3","15"],["4","16"]]

console.log(inputArr.reduce(([a,b],[c,d])=>(c.endsWith('x') && b.add(c),
  a.push([b.has(c+'x')?c+'x':c, d]), [a,b]),[[], new Set])[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```js
        const inputArr = [
            ["1.3","6"],
            ["1.4", "7"],
            ["1.4", "7"],
            ["1.4x", "s"],
            ["1.4x", "g"],
            ["1.4x", "9"], //here is an element with tailing 'x', 
                            //search for "1.4" in the next subarrays 
            ["2","8"],     
            ["2.1x","9"],
            ["2.2.2","12"],
            ["1.4", "13"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
            ["1.4", "14"], //found "1.4" here. change it to "1.4x"
            ["2.1","92"],
            ["3","15"],
            ["4","16"],
        ]
        const inputArrLen = inputArr.length;

        const newArr = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < inputArrLen; i++) {
            if (inputArr[i][0].endsWith('x')) {
                for (let j = i + 1; j < inputArrLen; j++) {
                    if (inputArr[j][0] == inputArr[i][0].slice(0, inputArr[i][0].length - 1)) {
                        inputArr[j][0] = inputArr[j][0] + 'x';
                    }
                }
            } 
            newArr.push(inputArr[i]);
        }
        console.log(newArr);
```